# Internals of Spark GroupBy and then Count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I read that in Apache Spark, GroupBy is a wide transformation meaning it requires data shuffle.My doubt is : Let's say I do `df.groupBy(column).count()`, so will the partitions first groupBy and count the values within their own partition and then share the result with the other partitions or will it be the case where data for similar keys are transfered to a common partition and then count operation would take place on each partition?

Comment: You can add `.explain()` to the end to see the Spark's DAG plan.

Comment: == Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[random_column#29], functions=[count(1)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(random_column#29, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#18]
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[random_column#29], functions=[partial_count(1)])
      +- FileScan json [random_column#29] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: JSON, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/home/ubuntu/work/Data/random_file.json], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<random_column:string>
===============================================================
Still not able to get the answer,

Comment: Reading from the bottom, you have `partial_count`, `hashpartitioning`, then `count` at top.  This means Spark does partial counting within the partition (`partial_count`), then shuffle and merge the result (`hashpartitioning`), then getting the final count (`count`).